# Set column order in contenttype

Tags: 2010, content-type, site-column, xml, ordering

I've added some site columns with an xml file and also created my contenttype in the xml. After deploying, a feature creates a lookup to another list (with c# code).
How can I set te column order in the contenttype that the new lookup column is placed between the other columns? If possible with c# code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that the fields order is from schema.xml

To chenge the order the key is :

SPFieldLinkCollection.Reorder

MSDN : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlinkcollection.reorder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

here i updated with powershell script.

http://suryapulipati.blogspot.com/2013/07/column-order-for-sharepoint-2010.html